# BAT File rename, based on selected part

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a file called:

> ```
> Jxxxxx xxx_xxx_xxx_Nov2_xx BLABLA xxx 1400 (N) Export.CSV
> ```

File name always different, could be sorter or longer, the only thing which stays the same is `BLABLA`.

What I need is something like this:

```
ren "*BLABLA*.CSV" "BLABLA.CSV"
```

Basically I need all file which include in the name `BLABLA` will be changed to `BLABLA.CSV`.

Comment: The `BLABLA` part is not there literally, right? What have you tried so far?

Comment: What happened when you used `ren "*BLABLA*.CSV" "BLABLA.CSV"`? In what way did this not meet your expectation. As @Magoo has said, there cannot be multiple files with the same name in a single directory. What is your plan on that?

Comment: @lit I have tried, but it doesn't rename it. Have no idea why. (There will be only single file, do not need for multiple.)

Comment: @aschipfl I have tried only ren "*BLABLA*.CSV" "BLABLA.CSV" , could not find any other way. P.S. There will be only one file like this, no multiple files with same BLABLA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ren *BLABLA*.csv BLABLA.csv
```

from your problem description. Of course, you can;t have more than one file by the same name, so the first will be renamed and you'll get an error for each other attempted rename.